# Equivalent of VCR for NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, vcr

We've written a basic networking application using C# and .net. For tests, we'd love to use something similar to [Ruby's VCR](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/vcr). Does such a thing exist for C#/.net ?

Comment: If there is such a thing, I don't know of it.  I'd love to add it to the list of ports in the VCR readme, though -- so please open a VCR pull request with links to any .NET porst you find!

Comment: there are two repos related to VCR, 1 is https://github.com/omnibs/service-ghost, another is https://github.com/matthew-cochran/Betamax.Net. Have tried Betamax and it works

Comment: There is also https://github.com/mleech/scotch